# How to display the time and date in the right time zone for me?

Tags: node.js, request

I have a request for adding data. And I want to display the date and time in the console with each new request. But  the time zone does not suit me when displaying the result.

The result looks like this:

> Thu, 18 Jul 2019 08:19:13 GMT

I would like to:

> Thu, 18 Jul 2019 13:19:13 GMT

request:

```
var options = {
    url: `http://localhost:5000/post`,
    method: 'POST',
    form: {
        ...
    },
    headers: {
        'Cookie': cookies
    }
};
try {
    var post = await request(options);
    console.log(post.headers.date);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment-timezone for displaying dates for particular timezone as mentioned below:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const date = moment("2019-06-18 14:40:00")
console.log(date.tz("Asia/Kolkata").format()) //2019-06-18T14:40:00+05:30
console.log(date.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format()) //2019-06-18T02:10:00.000-07:00
```

For more details refer [moment-timezone documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment js to format the request data

console.log(moment(post.headers.date).format("DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"));

Comment: This will not change the time zone.